# ValueError: Unhandled object <_io.TextIOWrapper name='world.json' mode='r' encoding='utf-8-sig'>

Tags: python, geojson

I am trying to change the colours of a countries using GeoJson polygon colour features.

This is the code that gives me an error.

```
import folium
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("Volcanoes_USA.txt")
lat = list(data["LAT"])
lon = list(data["LON"])
elev = list(data["ELEV"])

def color_producer(elevation):
    if elevation < 1000:
        return 'green'
    elif 1000 <= elevation < 3000:
        return 'orange'
    else:
        return 'red'

map = folium.Map(location=[38.58,-99.09], zoom_start=6, tiles="Mapbox Bright")

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")

for lt,ln,el in zip(lat, lon, elev):
    fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln], radius = 6, popup=str(el)+ " m", color = color_producer(el), fill_color= 'grey', fill_opacity=1.15))

fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json','r', encoding='utf-8-sig'),
style_function = lambda x: {'fillColour':'yellow'}))
```

The last two lines result in the following error message:

```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "map1.py", line 25, in <module>
>     style_function = lambda x: {'fillColour':'yellow'}))   File "/Users/g_wauns/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/features.py",
> line 495, in __init__
>     raise ValueError('Unhandled object {!r}.'.format(data)) ValueError: Unhandled object <_io.TextIOWrapper name='world.json'
> mode='r' encoding='utf-8-sig'>.
```

Since I am new to coding, I on't know what this means.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [[GitHub]: (**master**) folium/folium/features.py:343](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/folium/features.py#L343) (**as it is at this point**), looks like `folium.GeoJson` constructor can only handle (**for your scenario**) either a:

1. File **name**
2. *Python* dictionary

So, the simplest way to solve this, is to just pass the file name:

```
fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson("world.json", style_function=lambda x: {"fillColour": "yellow"}))
```

Of course, you could read the file yourself into a *dict* (using the [[Python]: *json* — JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module), but it's just what the above file does ~20 lines below.

Answer (score 1):

just add `read()` for data

```
fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read(), style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor':'yellow'}))
```

This did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved the exact same problem above with the code found in the following code block

```
import folium
import pandas
import json

data = pandas.read_csv("Volcanoes_USA.csv")
```

I had to create the following line as a str function to get my code to work
in reading the world.json file correctly. The example in the course was not
working for me. I had to therefore import the json Library and read in the file
first with the encoding and then pass it on the GeoJson method
described further down in the code

```
data_json = open("world.json", 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()

lat = list(data["LAT"])
long = list(data["LON"])
elev = list(data["ELEV"])
name = list(data["NAME"])

def pin_color(elev):
    if elev <= 1500.0:
        return "green"
    elif elev >= 3000.0:
        return "red"
    else:
        return "orange"

map = folium.Map(location=[38.58,-99.09], zoom_start=6, control_scale=True,
tiles="Stamen Terrain")
map.add_child(folium.LatLngPopup())
map

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="my_map")
```

I was not able to use the line as explained in the course which was:
fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json', 'r', encoding=utf-8-sig)))
So I defined data_json as mentioned above in this code as a str to be read below
by folium.GeoJson.

```
fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=data_json,
style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor':'green' if x['properties'] 
['POP2005'] < 10000000
else 'orange' if 10000000 <= x['properties']['POP2005'] < 20000000 else 
'red' }))

for i,j,z,v in zip(lat, long, elev, name):
    icn_pin=folium.Popup(str(v)+" Volcano"+": "+"Elevation:"+str(z)+"m "+" 
    "+"Lat:"+str(i)+" "+"Long:"+str(j),parse_html=True)
    fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[i,j], popup=icn_pin, 
    radius=7, fill=True, color=pin_color(z), fill_color=pin_color(z), 
    fill_opacity=0.85))

map.add_child(fg)
map.save("world_pop_map.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

As user9608587 has posted it helped me to get an idea how to get this done

I imported 'io' module and used io.open() function.

```
import io
data_json = io.open("world.json",'r',encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
```

Final code, you can just copy and paste it, it will work.

```
import folium
import pandas,io

data = pandas.read_csv("Volcanoes_USA.txt")
data_json = io.open("world.json",'r',encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
lat = list(data.LAT)
lon = list(data.LON)
elev = list(data.ELEV)

def colour_producer(elev):
    if elev<1000:
        return "green"
    elif 1000<= elev <3000:
        return "orange"
    else:
        return "red"

Map = folium.Map(location=[38.58,-99.09],zoom_start=6,tiles = "Mapbox Bright")
fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")

'''for lat,lon,elev in zip(lat,lon,elev):
    fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lat,lon],popup=str(elev) + "m",radius
    = 6,fill_color = colour_producer(elev),
    color = 'grey',fill_opacity = 0.7))'''

fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=data_json,style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor':'blue' if x['properties']
['POP2005'] < 10000000
else 'green' if 10000000 <= x['properties']['POP2005'] < 20000000 else
'red' }))


Map.add_child(fg)
Map.save("Map1.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data = (open("world.json", "r", encoding=("utf-8-sig"))).read()))

Comment: This exact answer has already been posted to this question. Also next time please add an explanation of why your answer is correct.